# Return a value from a function and display it in the template [ VUE JS ]

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js

I have a simple problem regarding returning a value from a function and displaying it inside the template tag in Vue js.
Inside the function, I got the value of color but when I display it in the template I go empty string, my question is how I can update the color value in the function and over right it with the function value?

```
<script setup>
  import {ref, watch} from 'vue';
  import { ColorPicker } from 'vue-color-kit';
  import 'vue-color-kit/dist/vue-color-kit.css'

  let color = ref('');
  let suckerCanvas = ref(null);
  let suckerArea = ref([]);
  let isSucking = ref(false);

  
  const changeColor = (color) => {
    const { r, g, b, a } = color.rgba;
    console.log(r,g,b,a + " RGBA VALUE");
    color.value =  `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, ${a})`;
    console.log(color + " COLOR VALUE");
  } 


  console.log(color.value);

</script>

<template>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <color-picker
            theme="dark"
            :color="color"
            :sucker-hide="false"
            :sucker-canvas="suckerCanvas"
            :sucker-area="suckerArea"
            @changeColor="changeColor"
            @openSucker="openSucker"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div :style="{background: suckerCanvas}" class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div :key="color">{{'The color is + ' + color}}</div>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: read the docs for the [Composition API](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/composition-api-faq.html#what-is-composition-api) which applies when using `<script setup>` and make all your `ref()`'s `const` ... like `const color = ref('')` - then when you slip up and try to use `color='whatever'` you'll get an error - which will remind you to use `.value`

Comment: I used also .value inside the function and nothing happened as well

Comment: you probably have a lot else going wrong - like you expect a string to have `.rgba` property - it does not

Comment: Inside the function Sir, I got the results of color which will have RGB value, and it won't appear in the template, so that's mainly my problem, so I just need to see the result in the template.

Comment: what are the expected values that `color` could have? what do you expect `color.rgba` (or would it be `color.value.rgba`) to contain?

Comment: rgba(73, 73, 73, 1) COLOR VALUE app.js:27607:15
76 76 76 1 RGBA VALUE app.js:27605:15 --- That's what is inside my console whenever I move the cursor the rgba is updated.

Comment: so, `color.value` is expected to be a **string** ... strings don't have a `rgba` property - how do you expect that to contain `{r, g, b, a}` ... what is `<color-picker` component? where is it from? where is it documented? perhaps that's the key to your problem

Comment: Besides the problem with rgba, the obvious mistake is that `color` is shadowed by the parameter of the same name, should be `const changeColor = (value) =>`

Comment: Your right unfortunately the documentation is not clear and uses the old syntax

Comment: https://www.vuescript.com/color-picker-kit/

Comment: that's not an issue ... EstusFlask is your hero - you are masking the color ref with the argument of that function! - i.e. `const changeColor = (value) => {
    const { r, g, b, a } = value.rgba;` then you can use `color.value = "whatever"`

Comment: Thank you both for your help now it worked, the suggestion made by Estus solved my problem. Have nice day fellows.

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <color-picker
            theme="dark"
            :color="color.value"
            :sucker-hide="false"
            :sucker-canvas="suckerCanvas"
            :sucker-area="suckerArea"
            @changeColor="changeColor"
            @openSucker="openSucker"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div :style="{background: suckerCanvas}" class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div :key="color">{{'The color is + ' + color}}</div>
</div>
</template>
```

***Change your template as I changed above***